# datetime arithmetic with microsecond resolution in Python

Tags: python, datetime, date-arithmetic, python-datetime

I want to calculate the difference (in terms of days, hour, min, sec, microsecond) between two time stamps (having microsecond resolution) in python e.g. between (1)`2016-05-10 11:32:18.025635` and (2) `2016-05-13 18:59:52.094672`

Any pointers, how to do it?

Comment: What *type* are those timestamps? Are they strings, or `datetime.datetime()` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`python-dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/2.5.3) package:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> d1 = dateutil.parser.parse('2016-05-10 11:32:18.025635')
>>> d2 = dateutil.parser.parse('2016-05-13 18:59:52.094672')
>>> d2 - d1
datetime.timedelta(3, 26854, 69037)
```

This will give you a [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object which represents the time difference between the two datetime objects.

If you don't want to install a package then it can also be done using [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) but in that case you have to define what the string looks like.

Comment: These are ISO timestamps, if strings. I suspect however that they are already `datetime` objects.